# Resampling with a Multiindex and several columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
ID    date           m_1   m_2 
 1    2016-01-03     10    3.4
      2016-02-07     11    3.3
      2016-02-07     10.4  2.8
 2    2016-01-01     10.9  2.5
      2016-02-04     12    2.3
      2016-02-04     11    2.7
      2016-02-04     12.1  2.1
```

Both `ID` and `date` are a `MultiIndex`. The data represent some measurements made by some sensors (in the example two sensors). Those sensors sometimes create several measurements per day (as shown in the example).

My questions are:

- How can I resample this so I have one row per day per sensor, but one column with the `mean`, another with the `max` another with `min`, etc?
- How can I "align" (maybe this is no the correct word) the two time series, so both begin and end at the same time (from `2016-01-01` to `2016-02-07`) adding the missing days with NAs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) and aggregate by functions in `dict` first and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('ID').resample('D').agg({'m_1':'mean', 'm_2':'max'})
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names = df.index.names))

#alternative for adding missing start and end datetimes
#df = df.unstack().stack(dropna=False)
print (df.head())
               m_2   m_1
ID date                 
1  2016-01-01  NaN   NaN
   2016-01-02  NaN   NaN
   2016-01-03  3.4  10.0
   2016-01-04  NaN   NaN
   2016-01-05  NaN   NaN
```

For `PeriodIndex` in second level use [`set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) with [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values('date').to_period('d'), level=1)

print (df.index.get_level_values('date'))

PeriodIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-04',
             '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08',
             '2016-01-09', '2016-01-10', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-12',
             '2016-01-13', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-15', '2016-01-16',
             '2016-01-17', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-19', '2016-01-20',
             '2016-01-21', '2016-01-22', '2016-01-23', '2016-01-24',
             '2016-01-25', '2016-01-26', '2016-01-27', '2016-01-28',
             '2016-01-29', '2016-01-30', '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01',
             '2016-02-02', '2016-02-03', '2016-02-04', '2016-02-05',
             '2016-02-06', '2016-02-07', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-02',
             '2016-01-03', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06',
             '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-09', '2016-01-10',
             '2016-01-11', '2016-01-12', '2016-01-13', '2016-01-14',
             '2016-01-15', '2016-01-16', '2016-01-17', '2016-01-18',
             '2016-01-19', '2016-01-20', '2016-01-21', '2016-01-22',
             '2016-01-23', '2016-01-24', '2016-01-25', '2016-01-26',
             '2016-01-27', '2016-01-28', '2016-01-29', '2016-01-30',
             '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-02', '2016-02-03',
             '2016-02-04', '2016-02-05', '2016-02-06', '2016-02-07'],
            dtype='period[D]', name='date', freq='D')
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Don't you think that the `date` should be a `Period` instead of a `Timestamp` now?

Comment: @nanounanue - No, there is no reason for it.

Comment: @nanounanue - You can check it by `print (df.index.get_level_values('date'))`

Comment: I apologize if my question wasn' t clear. What I mean (in the comment) is if there is a easy way of convert the `date` index to a `Period`

Comment: Yes, it is possible, do you need month or day period?